# How do I authenticate OneDrive for Business with Service to Service oauth2 authentication?

Tags: api, onedrive

The tutorial for OneDrive for Business (here: https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/aad_oauth.htm)

However, I don't want the user to have to login as I'm building a web API - I want the app to login. So, I have followed the tutorial for service to service authentication (here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx) which gets me an access token.

However, when I try to authenticate with the service I get an error saying "unsupported app only token". The code I'm using is below (btw, I'm using RestSharp):

```
public string GetAccessToken()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2");
        var request = new RestRequest("token", Method.POST);

        request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        request.AddParameter("client_id", <client_id>);
        request.AddParameter("client_secret", <client_secert);
        request.AddParameter("resource", "https://<tenant>-my.sharepoint.com/");


        var response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content;
        var authModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthResponseModel>(content);

        return authModel.AccessToken;
    }
```

this gets me the access token

This is how I try to access my drive:

```
    public string GetDrive()
    {

        var accessToken = GetAccessToken();

        var client = new RestClient("https://<tenant>-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/");
        var request = new RestRequest("drive", Method.GET);

        request.AddHeader("Authorization: Bearer", accessToken);

        var response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content;

        return content;
    }
```

Does anyone have any tips? This is getting slightly maddening.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?